# EMACS and TAB key (indent vs \t insert)

Tags: emacs, indentation

Let's say I have a `<weird language>` file and I'm editing it.

If the cursor is at the beginning of a sentence (let's say an `if`, which is already indented 2 levels) and I hit `TAB`, I'd expect EMACS to increase +1 the indent level of that line (using a `TAB` or `N SPACEs`, depending on the indent style used in the file).

Anyways, if I hit `TAB` and the cursor is after the `if`, I'd expect EMACS to insert a plain `\t`.

How can I make EMACS behave like this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Took current indentation as at-beginning. That condition might need a modification. See also third clause.

```
(defun my-indent-or-insert-tab ()
  "Insert a TAB or indent depending on context. "
  (interactive "*")
  (cond((eq (current-column) (current-indentation)) 
        (indent-for-tab-command))
       ((member (char-after) (list ?\t ? ?\n))
        (insert "\t"))
       (t (message "%s" "Don't know what to do if inside word"))))
```

Comment: Give me a few hours to test this, please :)

Comment: I tried it but Emacs is not doing anything at all when I hit TAB. Is there something more that I should setup apart from pasting this in my .emacs?